# Sketch within note app is not available on my Macbook Air 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, notes.app, macos

Is there a way to tun sketch on? Because I can't see any icon to start drawing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of the new Notes.app from the Apple website. It doesn't have a sketch function, which makes me think that sketch is probably only available in iOS.

[image: What's new in Notes screenshot]

Comment: It is strange, as Mail gained scribbling additions through Preview integration in Yosemite, that Notes does not support them, but for now they are iOS 9 only. You can view them both iCloud and the Mac client, but only create them on iOS 9.